# Referencing another excel tab in VBA function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Once the VBA function conditionals are met, I want the function to execute the normal excel formula below:

**=SUMIF('Barclays - Interest'A:C, CONCATENATE(A1,"-",B1),'Barclays - Interest'C:C)**

```
  Function RECON (AccountName, Broker, Forex)
     If AccountName = "Barclays" Then 
         RECON = SUMIF('Barclays - Interest'A:C, CONCATENATE(AccountName,"-",Broker),'Barclays - Interest'C:C)
```

The above code is what I'd essentially like to achieve, any ideas on a workaround to this? (*This failed for me each time*) Ideally I'd like to keep the formula format the same so colleagues without VBA knowledge can easily manipulate it based off future data changes.

Comment: Need a little more context, this looks like something that doesn't really need to be a VBA formula. I usually like to avoid using VBA unless I absolutely have to. Why not just create a nested if with the conditions right in the spreadsheet?

Comment: For display purposes this would be the most efficient process, as there is eventually going to be over 20 separate conditionals applied. If there would be a change to a process, a nested if would require a lot of time to decipher from an outside perspective.

Comment: I guess I would need to see more to fully understand, since this appears to be something that would only occupy one cell per sheet it makes a lot of sense to me to use the choose() function and just have all 20 possible outputs in a skeleton sheet this way I could more easily visualize my different conditions. But I guess if you already have a VBA framework around it already it makes sense. Basically I make a skeleton sheet where you can configure things this way the novice doesn't even have to enter VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable to store your sheet name and just reference the range.

```
Function RECON(AccountName, Broker, Forex)

    If AccountName = "Barclays" Then
        Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Barclays - Interest")
        RECON = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ws.Range("A:C"), CONCATENATE(AccountName, "-", Broker), ws.Range("C:C"))

    '.... More Code
    '.... Make sure to END that IF

End Function
```

---

You may also want to give `RECON` a variable type. Long? Double? idk.

```
Function RECON(AccountName, Broker, Forex) as [Variable Type]
```

Comment: thank you for the response, since the formula could change frequently, would there be a way to use Application.Evaluate(SUMIF('Barclays - Interest'A:C, CONCATENATE(A1,"-",B1),'Barclays - Interest'C:C)) while having A1 and B1 be AccountName and Broker?

Comment: Sounds like something you could just try and find out

Comment: I'll give it a go, still new to VBA. Background is in Python and SQL.

Comment: When using `Evaluate` you need to be careful about the context in which the formula is calculated: Application.Evaluate uses the ActiveSheet (so A1 etc would come from there) whereas sheetReference.Evaluate uses the context of sheetReference.

Comment: @TimWilliams I think I might've found a way, but I would need to get the cell location of the variable passed through the formula RECON (AccountName, Broker, Forex). Any ideas on how to get the cell location of AccountName?

Comment: Declare `AccountName as Range` in the function parameters, then you can access that cell inside the function

Comment: @TimWilliams is there a way to declare that within my conditional, because I would still need that variable's value later on.

Comment: @urdearboy I was able to run the script when removing the CONCATENATE() section, when I include that it throws a compile error saying the function isn't defined. Any ideas on how I can alter this to work?

Comment: Application.wotksheetfunction.concatenate

Comment: @urdearboy getting a value error for the following: RECON = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(IE_ws2.Range("A:C"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Concatenate(CustodianAccount, "-", InvestmentID), IE_ws2.Range("C:C"))